# Tiki Net_LDAP2 class loading

Tags: tiki-wiki

I have a problem when I tried to integrate tiki with my LDAP server. In the test_ldap.php I wrote the code to debug according to this website (https://doc.tiki.org/LDAP%20authentication). This code returned a success. So I know that my LDAP is working fine. I have a problem at

```
$entry = Net_LDAP2_Entry::createConnected($this->_ldap, $this->_entry);
```

In the shiftEntry function in Search.php. When I return debug in here, it goes to ClassLoader.php and it go to

```
register_shutdown_function(function () {
TikiLib::events()->trigger('tiki.process.shutdown', []);});
```

In my opinion, maybe the problem is the

```
spl_autoload_call
```

The spl_autoload_call function called Net_LDAP2 which extends PEAR somewhere before this line in Search.php. This would lead both Net_LDAP2 and PEAR and PEAR_ERROR... Then when it comes to Net_LDAP2_Entry class, it would also load PEAR.... Would this create a fatal error?

I keep having blank screen in my tiki. Tried to cut the code from Search.php to the test_ldap.php to test. It has the same problem.

I am using:
Version 16.2
OS: Clear OS
Thanks for your help. I am blocked now.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a good start: https://dev.tiki.org/item6283. If you look in the comments by albertgi he states changing some function names in PEAR.php. I was having LDAP integration problems and this was one of the key problems.

Comment: Thanks. I found the problem was that the constructor in Net/LDAP2/Entry.php is declared protected. This causes the fatal error from the PHP. After changing from Protected to Public, it is now working.